# PostgreSQL query: selecting devices and their one parameter according to devices' another parameter's value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `Configuration`. The 1st column of the table is `deviceId`, the 2nd column is `parameter`, 3rd column is `value`.

In the table, there are many devices, each device has only one device ID(column 1); each device has many config parameters(column 2), ex. `VER`, `DATE`, etc, all devices have the same config parameters; the parameter's value(column 3) for different devices may be the same or not.

I want to select all devices' config parameter `VER` for those devices which have the `DATE` value larger than **'2019-05-01'**.

How can I achieve this in one `PostgreSQL` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `COUNT` as analytic function to identify matching devices:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT deviceId, parameter, value,
        COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE parameter = 'DATE' AND value > '2019-05-01') OVER
            (PARTITION BY deviceId) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT parameter, value
FROM cte
WHERE parameter = 'VER' AND cnt > 0;
```

### Demo

Another way to do this would be via an exists query:

```
SELECT parameter, value
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    parameter = 'VER' AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
            WHERE t1.deviceId = t2.deviceId AND
                  t2.parameter = 'DATE' AND
                  t2.value > '2019-05-01');
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, what does "SELECT 1" mean in exists query:

Comment: @leilei You may think of `SELECT 1` as just a "dummy" select.  We don't really care about what is being selected, because `EXISTS` just checks that _any_ sort of record exists.

Comment: @leilei: you can just as well write `select *` or `select 'this is ignored'` - actually in Postgres you could even write `select from ...` without any column names.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Didn't know about `SELECT FROM` ... nice comment :-)

Comment: You can even use `select 1/0` proving that the value is completely ignored.